# How to build Braintree iOS SDK as framework

Tags: ios, xamarin, braintree, ios-frameworks

I want to use braintree payment sdk in my Xamarin app. For that I need to have build braintree sdk as Framework. The guide described [here](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ios/guide/ios_installation) explains how to add Braintree manually or by cocoapods, but it doesn't explain how can I build the Braintree as a framework which can be reused in several projects, in my current case I need the framework to create Xamarin binding.

So How can I build braintree sdk as framework?

Comment: Hi, try this https://github.com/exchangegroup/braintree-framework-builder

Comment: Hello, thanks for this. When I needed this there wasn't such thing so I did manually. But good, that there is such resource already.